# Update Database and datagridview from textboxes

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, textbox

I have an application with a datagridview on the bottom half of the page and textboxes, combo-boxes, buttons, etc... on the top half.
When the user changes the highlighted row in the grid then it displays all of the information for that row in the objects on the top half.
If user wants to change the data in a row then he clicks an edit button which enables the textboxes etc... and allows the user to edit the data.
(All of the above works fine).

When he wants to save the changes then he clicks the save button.
This should update the datasource to the grid and show the changes in the grid.
However, I have been unable to get it do this.

Any Help appreciated.
Code below:

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient

Public Class frmEmployeeInformation
Public SQL As New SQLControl()
Dim strEditType As String

Private Sub frmEmployeeInformation_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    LoadGrid()
End Sub

Public Sub LoadGrid(Optional query As String = "")
    If query = "" Then
        SQL.ExecuteQuery("Select * from EmployeeInformation;")
    Else
        SQL.ExecuteQuery(query)
    End If
    If SQL.HasException(True) Then Exit Sub
    dgvEmployeeInformation.DataSource = SQL.DBDS.Tables(0)
    dgvEmployeeInformation.Rows(0).Selected = True
    SQL.DBDA.UpdateCommand = New SqlClient.SqlCommandBuilder(SQL.DBDA).GetUpdateCommand
End Sub

Private Sub DisplayValues()
    If dgvEmployeeInformation.RowCount > 2 Then
        If dgvEmployeeInformation.Rows(dgvEmployeeInformation.CurrentRow.Index).Cells("FirstName").Value <> Nothing Then
            txtFirstName.Text = dgvEmployeeInformation.Rows(dgvEmployeeInformation.CurrentRow.Index).Cells("FirstName").Value.ToString 'EmployeeInformation.FirstName
        End If

        If dgvEmployeeInformation.Rows(dgvEmployeeInformation.CurrentRow.Index).Cells("LastName").Value <> Nothing Then
            txtLastName.Text = dgvEmployeeInformation.Rows(dgvEmployeeInformation.CurrentRow.Index).Cells("LastName").Value.ToString 'EmployeeInformation.LastName
        End If

        If dgvEmployeeInformation.Rows(dgvEmployeeInformation.CurrentRow.Index).Cells("SSN").Value IsNot Nothing Then
            txtSSN.Text = dgvEmployeeInformation.Rows(dgvEmployeeInformation.CurrentRow.Index).Cells("SSN").Value.ToString 'EmployeeInformation.SSN
        End If

        If dgvEmployeeInformation.Rows(dgvEmployeeInformation.CurrentRow.Index).Cells("EmployeeInformationID").Value <> Nothing Then
            txtEmployeeID.Text = dgvEmployeeInformation.Rows(dgvEmployeeInformation.CurrentRow.Index).Cells("EmployeeInformationID").Value.ToString 'EmployeeInformation.EmployeeInformationID
        End If

        'If dgvEmployeeInformation.Rows(dgvEmployeeInformation.CurrentRow.Index).Cells("ADPID").Value <> Nothing Then
        'txtADPID.Text = dgvEmployeeInformation.Rows(dgvEmployeeInformation.CurrentRow.Index).Cells("ADPID").Value.ToString 'EmployeeInformation.ADPID
        'End If

        'If dgvEmployeeInformation.Rows(dgvEmployeeInformation.CurrentRow.Index).Cells("VP").Value <> Nothing Then
        'cboVP.Text = dgvEmployeeInformation.Rows(dgvEmployeeInformation.CurrentRow.Index).Cells("VP").Value.ToString 'EmployeeInformation.VP
        'End If

        If dgvEmployeeInformation.Rows(dgvEmployeeInformation.CurrentRow.Index).Cells("Default_LocationID").Value <> Nothing Then
            cboDefaultLocation.Text = dgvEmployeeInformation.Rows(dgvEmployeeInformation.CurrentRow.Index).Cells("Default_LocationID").Value.ToString 'EmployeeInformation.DefaultLocation
        End If

        If dgvEmployeeInformation.Rows(dgvEmployeeInformation.CurrentRow.Index).Cells("SystemTableID").Value <> Nothing Then
            txtTableID.Text = dgvEmployeeInformation.Rows(dgvEmployeeInformation.CurrentRow.Index).Cells("SystemTableID").Value.ToString 'EmployeeInformation.TableID
        End If

        If dgvEmployeeInformation.Rows(dgvEmployeeInformation.CurrentRow.Index).Cells("EmployeeActive").Value <> Nothing Then
            chkbxActive.Checked = dgvEmployeeInformation.Rows(dgvEmployeeInformation.CurrentRow.Index).Cells("EmployeeActive").Value.ToString 'EmployeeInformation.EmployeeActive
        End If

        If dgvEmployeeInformation.Rows(dgvEmployeeInformation.CurrentRow.Index).Cells("PrimaryFile").Value <> Nothing Then
            chkbxPrimaryFile.Checked = dgvEmployeeInformation.Rows(dgvEmployeeInformation.CurrentRow.Index).Cells("PrimaryFile").Value.ToString 'EmployeeInformation.PrimaryFile
        End If

        If dgvEmployeeInformation.Rows(dgvEmployeeInformation.CurrentRow.Index).Cells("UnallocatedTime").Value <> Nothing Then
            chkbxUnallocatedTime.Checked = dgvEmployeeInformation.Rows(dgvEmployeeInformation.CurrentRow.Index).Cells("UnallocatedTime").Value.ToString 'EmployeeInformation.UnallocatedTime
        End If
    End If
End Sub
Private Sub ChangeButtons()
    btnClose.Enabled = Not btnClose.Enabled
    btnSave.Enabled = Not btnSave.Enabled
    btnClear.Enabled = Not btnClear.Enabled
    btnFind.Enabled = Not btnFind.Enabled
    btnCancel.Enabled = Not btnCancel.Enabled
    btnEdit.Enabled = Not btnEdit.Enabled
    btnAdd.Enabled = Not btnAdd.Enabled
    btnCopy.Enabled = Not btnCopy.Enabled
End Sub

Private Sub ChangeFields()
    chkbxActive.Enabled = Not chkbxActive.Enabled
    chkbxPrimaryFile.Enabled = Not chkbxPrimaryFile.Enabled
    chkbxUnallocatedTime.Enabled = Not chkbxUnallocatedTime.Enabled
    txtTableID.Enabled = Not txtTableID.Enabled
    txtADPID.Enabled = Not txtADPID.Enabled
    cboVP.Enabled = Not cboVP.Enabled
    cboDefaultLocation.Enabled = Not cboDefaultLocation.Enabled
End Sub

Private Sub btnClose_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnClose.Click
    Me.Close()
End Sub

Private Sub btnFind_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnFind.Click
    If txtEmployeeID.Text <> "" Then
        SQL.AddParam("@EmployeeInformationID", txtEmployeeID.Text)
        LoadGrid("select * from EmployeeInformation where EmployeeInformationID = @EmployeeInformationID;")
    ElseIf txtSSN.Text <> "" Then
        SQL.AddParam("@SSN", txtSSN.Text)
        LoadGrid("select * from EmployeeInformation where SSN = @SSN;")
    ElseIf txtFirstName.Text <> "" And txtLastName.Text <> "" Then
        SQL.AddParam("@FirstName", txtFirstName.Text)
        SQL.AddParam("@LastName", txtLastName.Text)
        LoadGrid("select * from EmployeeInformation where FirstName = @FirstName and LastName = @LastName;")
    Else
        LoadGrid("Select * from EmployeeInformation;")
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub btnClear_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnClear.Click
    txtFirstName.Text = ""
    txtLastName.Text = ""
    txtSSN.Text = ""
    txtEmployeeID.Text = ""
    txtADPID.Text = ""
    cboVP.Text = ""
    cboDefaultLocation.Text = ""
    txtTableID.Text = ""
    chkbxActive.Checked = "False"
    chkbxPrimaryFile.Checked = "False"
    chkbxUnallocatedTime.Checked = "False"
End Sub

Private Sub dgvEmployeeInformation_DoubleClick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles dgvEmployeeInformation.DoubleClick
    DisplayValues()
    ChangeFields()
    ChangeButtons()
End Sub

Private Sub dgvEmployeeInformation_SelectionChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles dgvEmployeeInformation.SelectionChanged
    DisplayValues()
End Sub

Private Sub btnSave_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSave.Click

    If strEditType = "Edit" Then
        ' The code below updates the grid but the changes are not saved to the database. Probably not the way to go
        dgvEmployeeInformation.Rows(dgvEmployeeInformation.CurrentRow.Index).Cells("FirstName").Value = txtFirstName.Text 'EmployeeInformation.FirstName
        dgvEmployeeInformation.Rows(dgvEmployeeInformation.CurrentRow.Index).Cells("LastName").Value = txtLastName.Text 'EmployeeInformation.LastName
        dgvEmployeeInformation.Rows(dgvEmployeeInformation.CurrentRow.Index).Cells("SSN").Value = txtSSN.Text 'EmployeeInformation.SSN
        dgvEmployeeInformation.Rows(dgvEmployeeInformation.CurrentRow.Index).Cells("EmployeeInformationID").Value = txtEmployeeID.Text 'EmployeeInformation.EmployeeInformationID
        dgvEmployeeInformation.Rows(dgvEmployeeInformation.CurrentRow.Index).Cells("Default_LocationID").Value = cboDefaultLocation.Text 'EmployeeInformation.DefaultLocation
        dgvEmployeeInformation.Rows(dgvEmployeeInformation.CurrentRow.Index).Cells("SystemTableID").Value = txtTableID.Text 'EmployeeInformation.TableID
        dgvEmployeeInformation.Rows(dgvEmployeeInformation.CurrentRow.Index).Cells("EmployeeActive").Value = chkbxActive.Checked 'EmployeeInformation.EmployeeActive
        dgvEmployeeInformation.Rows(dgvEmployeeInformation.CurrentRow.Index).Cells("PrimaryFile").Value = chkbxPrimaryFile.Checked 'EmployeeInformation.PrimaryFile
        dgvEmployeeInformation.Rows(dgvEmployeeInformation.CurrentRow.Index).Cells("UnallocatedTime").Value = chkbxUnallocatedTime.Checked 'EmployeeInformation.UnallocatedTime
        ' The code above updates the grid but the changes are not saved to the database.
        dgvEmployeeInformation.EndEdit()
        SQL.DBDS.Tables(0).AcceptChanges()
        SQL.DBDA.Update(SQL.DBDS)
        'txtADPID.Text = dgvEmployeeInformation.Rows(dgvEmployeeInformation.CurrentRow.Index).Cells("ADPID").Value.ToString 'EmployeeInformation.ADPID
        'cboVP.Text = dgvEmployeeInformation.Rows(dgvEmployeeInformation.CurrentRow.Index).Cells("VP").Value.ToString 'EmployeeInformation.VP
    End If
    ChangeFields()
    ChangeButtons()
    strEditType = ""
    'LoadGrid()
End Sub

Private Sub btnCancel_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnCancel.Click
    ChangeFields()
    ChangeButtons()
    strEditType = ""
End Sub

Private Sub btnEdit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnEdit.Click
    dgvEmployeeInformation_DoubleClick(Nothing, EventArgs.Empty)
    strEditType = "Edit"
End Sub

Private Sub btnAdd_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnAdd.Click
    btnClear_Click(Nothing, EventArgs.Empty)
    txtFirstName.Focus()
    strEditType = "Add"
    ChangeFields()
    ChangeButtons()

End Sub

Private Sub btnCopy_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnCopy.Click
    cboDefaultLocation.Focus()
    strEditType = "Copy"
    ChangeFields()
    ChangeButtons()

End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: To format your code correctly, you need four spaces and a newline at the start.  I've added these for you at the start and end, but it makes the rest of your code indentation not quite right.  

Also, is this VBA or VB.NET.  You didn't tag with either one (you had only written "Visual Basic" in the title), so I guessed and added the `vb.net` tag.  If it's wrong, please edit the question to include it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it to work:

```
    Private Sub btnSave_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSave.Click
    Dim dbconn As New SqlConnection("server=192.168.50.205;Database=SEMHC_Admin2018;trusted_Connection=True;")
    Dim mycmd As SqlCommand
    Dim mySQL As String

    dbconn.Open()

    If strEditType = "Add" Or strEditType = "Copy" Then
    End If

    If strEditType = "Edit" Then
        mySQL = "update employeeInformation 
                            set FirstName = @firstName,
                                LastName = @LastName,
                                SSN = @SSN,
                                EmployeeInformationID = @EmployeeInformationID,
                                Default_LocationID = @Default_LocationID,
                                EmployeeActive = @chkbxActive,
                                PrimaryFile = @chkbxPrimaryFile,
                                UnallocatedTime = @chkbxUnallocatedTime
                                from employeeInformation
                                WHERE SystemTableID = @SystemTableID
                         " 'write query'    
        mycmd = New SqlCommand(mySQL, dbconn)
        mycmd.Parameters.Add("@SystemTableID", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtTableID.Text
        mycmd.Parameters.Add("@FirstName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtFirstName.Text
        mycmd.Parameters.Add("@LastName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtLastName.Text
        mycmd.Parameters.Add("@SSN", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtSSN.Text
        mycmd.Parameters.Add("@EmployeeInformationID", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtEmployeeID.Text
        mycmd.Parameters.Add("@Default_LocationID", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = cboDefaultLocation.Text
        mycmd.Parameters.Add("@chkbxActive", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = chkbxActive.Checked
        mycmd.Parameters.Add("@chkbxPrimaryFile", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = chkbxPrimaryFile.Checked
        mycmd.Parameters.Add("@chkbxUnallocatedTime", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = chkbxUnallocatedTime.Checked
        mycmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        'MsgBox("Update complete.")
        dbconn.Close()
        'SQL.DBDS.Tables(0).AcceptChanges()
        'SQL.DBDA.Update(SQL.DBDS)
        'txtADPID.Text = dgvEmployeeInformation.Rows(dgvEmployeeInformation.CurrentRow.Index).Cells("ADPID").Value.ToString 'EmployeeInformation.ADPID
        'cboVP.Text = dgvEmployeeInformation.Rows(dgvEmployeeInformation.CurrentRow.Index).Cells("VP").Value.ToString 'EmployeeInformation.VP
    End If
    ChangeFields()
    ChangeButtons()
    strEditType = ""
    LoadGrid()
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

**TRY ANOTHER WAY!!**

I suggest you, instead of doing this:

```
If strEditType = "Edit" Then
    ' The code below updates the grid but the changes are not saved to the database. Probably not the way to go
    dgvEmployeeInformation.Rows(dgvEmployeeInformation.CurrentRow.Index).Cells("FirstName").Value = txtFirstName.Text 'EmployeeInformation.FirstName
    dgvEmployeeInformation.Rows(dgvEmployeeInformation.CurrentRow.Index).Cells("LastName").Value = txtLastName.Text 'EmployeeInformation.LastName
    dgvEmployeeInformation.Rows(dgvEmployeeInformation.CurrentRow.Index).Cells("SSN").Value = txtSSN.Text 'EmployeeInformation.SSN
    dgvEmployeeInformation.Rows(dgvEmployeeInformation.CurrentRow.Index).Cells("EmployeeInformationID").Value = txtEmployeeID.Text 'EmployeeInformation.EmployeeInformationID
    dgvEmployeeInformation.Rows(dgvEmployeeInformation.CurrentRow.Index).Cells("Default_LocationID").Value = cboDefaultLocation.Text 'EmployeeInformation.DefaultLocation
    dgvEmployeeInformation.Rows(dgvEmployeeInformation.CurrentRow.Index).Cells("SystemTableID").Value = txtTableID.Text 'EmployeeInformation.TableID
    dgvEmployeeInformation.Rows(dgvEmployeeInformation.CurrentRow.Index).Cells("EmployeeActive").Value = chkbxActive.Checked 'EmployeeInformation.EmployeeActive
    dgvEmployeeInformation.Rows(dgvEmployeeInformation.CurrentRow.Index).Cells("PrimaryFile").Value = chkbxPrimaryFile.Checked 'EmployeeInformation.PrimaryFile
    dgvEmployeeInformation.Rows(dgvEmployeeInformation.CurrentRow.Index).Cells("UnallocatedTime").Value = chkbxUnallocatedTime.Checked 'EmployeeInformation.UnallocatedTime
    ' The code above updates the grid but the changes are not saved to the database.
    dgvEmployeeInformation.EndEdit()
    SQL.DBDS.Tables(0).AcceptChanges()
    SQL.DBDA.Update(SQL.DBDS)
    'txtADPID.Text = dgvEmployeeInformation.Rows(dgvEmployeeInformation.CurrentRow.Index).Cells("ADPID").Value.ToString 'EmployeeInformation.ADPID
    'cboVP.Text = dgvEmployeeInformation.Rows(dgvEmployeeInformation.CurrentRow.Index).Cells("VP").Value.ToString 'EmployeeInformation.VP
End If
```

to first update your DB and than to update the datagrid from your DB.

*Something like*

```
Sql = "update TABLE_Name set FirstName = @fName" 'write all your query'    
myCmd = New SqlCommand(Sql, myConn)
myCmd.Parameters.Add("@fName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtFirstName.Text 
myCmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
MsgBox("Update complete.")
myConn.Close()
```

And than you can update your datagrid! I'm always used to connect my DataGrid to my SQL table, so the code will be:

```
Public Sub Updating()
    Me.Table_NameTableAdapter.Fill(Me.DB_NameDataSet1.Table_Name)
End Sub
```